# How to scroll to center of a horizontal UIScrollView with dynamic content to the selected item?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a unique problem where I need to scroll to a selected uiview point in my horizontal scrollView so the item is always centered when the view loads. At first glance it seems easy to scroll to the center of a scrollview, but the number of items in the internal stackView can be of n size. However, I do know the point that needs to be scrolled to since it's the selected item in the stackView when the view loads front the model.

Here's some code I tried:

```
   func scrollToSelectedItem(_ item: SelectedItem) {
        var toPoint = item.frame.origin
        // Find the center points of the superview and the item.
        toPoint.x -= bounds.width / 2 - item.bounds.width / 2
        toPoint.x += scrollView.contentInset.left
        scrollView.setContentOffset(toPoint, animated: true)
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let numberOfItems = contentStackView.arrangedSubviews.count
        let proposedOffset = targetContentOffset.pointee.x + scrollView.contentInset.left
        let pageWidth = 200
        let targetIndex = min(CGFloat(numberOfItems - 1), max(0, proposedOffset / pageWidth)).rounded()
        let pagedOffset = targetIndex * pageWidth - scrollView.contentInset.left
        targetContentOffset.pointee.x = pagedOffset
        guard let item = contentStackView.arrangedSubviews[Int(targetIndex)] as? SelectedItem else { return }
        scrollToSelectedItem(item)
    }
```

My first thought was to use the scroll view delegate to detect dragging and use the number of items in the stackview to determine the necessary point information, but this doesn't seem to be working at all or I am overcomplicating it. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
Before view appears:
|------------------------screen-------------------------------|
                        
|----- Item 1 -----| |----- Item 2 -----| |----- Item 3 -----| |----- Item 4 -----| |----- Selected 5 -----| |----- Item 6 -----|
                         ^ current center                                                     ^ new center     
|------------------------horizontal stackview ------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------horizontal scrollview------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

After view appears:

                                                              |------------------------screen-------------------------------|
                        
|----- Item 1 -----| |----- Item 2 -----| |----- Item 3 -----| |----- Item 4 -----| |----- Selected 5 -----| |----- Item 6 -----|
                         ^ old center                                                         ^ current center
|------------------------horizontal stackview ------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|------------------------horizontal scrollview------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Why not using scrollRectToVisible ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my friends:

```html
        if let chosenItem = selectedItem {
            // Recalculate content size
            layoutIfNeeded()
            var toPoint = chosenItem.frame.origin
            // Find the center points of the superview and the item.
            toPoint.x -= bounds.width / 2 - item.bounds.width / 2
            toPoint.x += scrollView.contentInset.left
            scrollView.setContentOffset(toPoint, animated: true)
        }
```

I needed to recalc the content size and got it to work!